# Bluetooth Audio with Playstation TV

Tags: ps-vita, playstation-tv

So, my family competes for TV time a lot.  So, I bought a playstation TV to use to stream remote play to my PC monitor.  That works great, except I can't get any sound.  None of my ordinary bluetooth devices seem to work.  They fail on the PSTV with "Could not find a profile supported by this system"  I suspect that it because the BT devices that I'm using aren't officially Sony sanctioned.  Plugging into a DS4 controller doesn't produce audio either.

Has anyone had a good experience with BT audio with this?

Comment: Does your PC monitor have speakers? Looking at the PS TV online, it seems that there's no audio-out jack, so it must transmit audio through HDMI. Unless your monitor has speakers or audio-out jack, I don't think there's a way you can split the signal.

Comment: Although if there's a BT Audio option, I suppose disregard my previous comment.